# SharePoint Backup Order

Tags: backup

We want to install June 2015 CU on SharePoint server 2010, as a backup strategy we will take a full Farm backup, SQL backup and Doc-Ave platform backup, to make sure these guys are not nullifying each other. what should be the best order of taking these backup(Farm, SQL and Doc-Ave)?

Answer (score 1):

You have more than enough copy of backups :).

I think order really doesnot matter, rather the timings. So which ever tool will perform backup on last minute( just before the start of cu process) should be last one.

If you ask me, i would prefer the SQL backup at the end.